# Is there a way to flatten a struct field in AWS Athena?

Tags: json, amazon-s3, hive, presto, amazon-athena

I'm trying to write an Athena query which will allow me to expand a struct inside of a select statement.

Lets say I have a table my_table which looks like:

```
id string,
metadata struct<field1:varchar,field2:int>
```

I know that by placing the name `field1` in the query I can pull the field from the struct, but I would like something more general such as `metadata.*` so schema can be abstract.

This can easily be done with Python and some libraries but wanted to check if there isn't anything that can be done inside Athena.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like it if something like `select results.id, results.scores.* from my_table results` worked, but unfortunately it doesn't.

What you're asking for is called "generalized all fields reference".
It is available in Presto since [Presto 323](https://trino.io/docs/current/release/release-323.html).
You can download the latest Presto release from https://trino.io/download.html.

Unfortunately, Athena is currently based on Presto .172 (released 3 years ago), so this functionality is not available there. Until Athena is upgraded, there is no workaround you can apply on SQL level. You need to compensate this within application reading the data from Athena. Or, you can [deploy recent Presto version on AWS easily](https://trino.io/resources.html#aws).

Comment: Athena engine 2 now based on presto `0.217`, but that is still < `0.323`, so no dice!

Comment: Just checking in, over a year later, and Athena is still on engine version 2 and Presto 0.217.